# Need to show column name in a row after taking transpose in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

```
features_df = (pd.concat(feature_weight_list)
                .pivot(index='n', columns='features', values='values'))
print(features_df)

features_df.to_csv (r'C:/Users/USER12/Downloads/AB.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

I am saving this file at its pattern is like that

feature 1 , feature 2 , feature 3

Then I am taking transpose but the feature column name is not appearing in rows

this is the code I am using. can anyone help

```
features_df_T = features_df.T
print(features_df_T)

features_df_T.to_csv (r'C:/Users/USER12/Downloads/transposeAB.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `index` to `False` in the `DataFrame.to_csv` method will remove the indexing, which has become the column names after the transposition of the dataframe. Try removing `index=False` when saving the dataframe to a csv file.

```
features_df_T.to_csv(r'C:/Users/USER12/Downloads/transposeAB.csv')
```